# Smooth swipe up animation (React Native Animation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-animation, react-native-animatable

**What do I expect to do:**

A modal screen that you can close by swiping up.

Inside the modal I have:

```
 componentWillMount() {
    this.animated = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,

        onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
            const { dy } = gestureState;
            if(dy < 0) {
                this.animated.setValue(dy);
            }
        },

        onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
            const { dy } = gestureState;

            if(dy < -100) { // Swipe up away
                Animated.timing(this.animated, {
                    toValue: -400,
                    duration: 150
                }).start();
                this.props.hideModal();
                this.doSomething();
            } else if(dy > -100 && dy < 0) { // Swipe back to initial position
                Animated.timing(this.animated, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 150
                }).start();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This Modal appears by clicking on a button in a parent component. By default in that parent there is a state value ***showModal : false***. Opening the Modal this state is changed to ***true*** and when closing to ***false***.

The main problem for now is that when you swipe for closing this Modal doesn't go up smoothly and disappear. It goes up to 100px, stops on a place and starts disappearing.

If remove ***this.props.hideModal()*** this Modal goes up to the top of a screen smoothly and disappears as I want, but it is not closed completely and you can not click on any other buttons after that.

Basically, I need to run ***this.props.hidModal()*** AFTER the animation has been finished.

How can I implement smooth closing of the Modal?
I hope I described my problem understandably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling `this.props.hideModal()` after the animatiom is finished is the fix (which I believe it is) you could pass this as a callback to `.start()`.

```
Animated.timing({..}).start(this.props.hideModal)
```